# Run a command third monday every month

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a artisan command that needs to be run the third monday of every month. I thought it should be easy with a simple cron rule saying "0 9 17-23 * 1", but now (a month after making the rule) I realize that my job has been run on EVERY monday of the month AND on EVERY day between the 17th and 23th. So obviously this doesn't work as I thought... After some googling it seems it's not easily solvable using only cron rules.

So, looking at the Laravel scheduling docs I *think* I have a solution, but I'm looking for verification I'm thinking right. If I instead do like this, will that do what I want? Don't want to try it the hard way again...

```
cron('0 9 17-23 * *')->mondays()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the cron you are looking for can not be done without an external script of some sort.

In your case, I would leave the cronjob as it is, and create a larvel command, where you would check if the current day is a Monday in the given date-range or not.

This can be done with Carbon with the following function:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $todaysDay = Carbon::today()->dayOfWeek;

        // 1 is monday in Carbon.
        if($todaysDay == 1){
            $startDate = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m'))->addDays(17);
            $endDate = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m'))->addDays(23);

            // Check if todays date is in the given date-range
            if(Carbon::now()->between($startDate, $endDate)){

                // This is a monday between the 17nth and the 23rd
                // Do your magic stuff here.

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sure that you could make this logic more effective, but this is a solution that solves your issue.

This command should then be ran by your cron :)

Comment: Thanks! It really is strange that this isn't solvable using standard stuff in the framework...

I ended up adding another argument to my command and doing this the first thing:
```
        if($this->argument('onlyOnWeekday')!='onlyOnWeekday=all' && 
            substr($this->argument('onlyOnWeekday'), -1)!=\Carbon\Carbon::today()->dayOfWeek) {
            return;
        }
```
(oh crap. Why wan't I use code fences in comments? Hope you get the picture anyway...)

Comment: @DanielMalmgren Aah i see, good job! Well, not every solution can be solved by a framework, but I agree to your statement. Have a nice one and good luck! :)